# Auto populate meta tags from other meta tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a website with multiple pages.. I'm adding going to have to add META tags to every page however I would like to know if there we a way to extract stuff from existing tags and add them to other tags.

So, for example these tags already exist in the static HTML pages:

```
<meta name="description" content="Description 01"/>
<title>Title 01</title>
```

Now any way to extract these values from every page and insert them as other tags into other pages.

So Home page would already contain:

```
<meta name="description" content="Description Home"/>
<title>Title Home</title>
```

and these would automatically be added:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="Title Home">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Description Home">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Title Home">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Description Home">
<meta property="og:title" content="Title Home" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description Home" />
```

And the contact page would already contain:

```
<meta name="description" content="Description Contact"/>
<title>Title Contact</title>
```

and these would automatically be added:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="Title Contact">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Description Contact">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Title Contact">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Description Contact">
<meta property="og:title" content="Title Contact" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description Contact" />
```

Comment: How are you serving your pages? Apache? Tomcat? Basically, you'll have to send all your static pages through some kind of middleware.

Comment: What does *"extract these values from every page"* mean precisely? Not at all clear what you are trying to do , where or what data source really is

Answer (score 0):

Make it dynamic instead

Create **header.php** then insert the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $page_desc ?>"/>
        <title><?php echo $page_title ?></title>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="<?php echo $page_title ?>">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="<?php echo $page_desc ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php echo $twt_title ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo $twt_desc ?>">
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $og_title ?>" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $og_desc ?>" />
    </head>
    <body>
```

Create **footer.php** then insert the following code

```
    </body></html>
```

Create **index.php** as your first page

```
<?php
    // the page title and description should be declared first before you include the header and footer
    $page_title = 'My Page Title';
    // same as the others
    $twt_title = $page_title;
    $og_title = $page_title;

    $page_desc = 'My Page Description';
    // same as the others
    $twt_desc = $page_desc;
    $og_desc = $page_desc;

    include 'header.php';
?>
<!-- some page contents -->
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Create **about.php** as another page

```
<?php
    // the page title and description should be declared first before you include the header and footer
    $page_title = 'About us';
    // same as the others
    $twt_title = $page_title;
    $og_title = $page_title;

    $page_desc = 'My Page Description';
    // same as the others
    $twt_desc = $page_desc;
    $og_desc = $page_desc;

    include 'header.php';
?>
<!-- some page contents -->
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```